# Restrict Users to download updated build from iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes, app-store-connect

I had a serious bug in my itunes latest updated build. I want to restrict users to update the current version. How?
any suggestions will help me a lot.

Comment: you can try "Removing an app from sale" http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no functionality built into the App Store to force updates.

In your initial version, you should add a way to force updates, and then test to ensure that it works. Typically, you will have a callback to the server and a way to display a message and link them to the update in the store.

If you don't have such functionality, and you are making any API calls, you can add a version number to the API call, and if the version isn't sent, then you can refuse access, and preferably send them a message.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean you want people who have the buggy version to update ?

unless you have push notifications setup with your app, or a means to display them a message, or have their emails as part of a sign up process, your very limited to what you can do.

If you have published the new version, just make it clear in the version notes that this includes a bug fix.